# How to globally signout a cognito user via aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I work with AWS Cognito. I have the attached code to globally signout a user based on access token :

```js
var signOut = (accessToken) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var params = {
      //UserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID, /* required */
      AccessToken: accessToken /* required */
    };
    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
      apiVersion: '2016-04-18',
      region: 'us-east-1'
    })
    console.log("Signing out user .. ");
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.globalSignOut(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        reject(err)
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data)
      }
    });
  });
```

and when I invoke the code I get the following  error:

> 2019-08-20T14:33:29.736Z   011d65cb-ee4d-4053-9283-6e6242560c6b    { NotAuthorizedException: Access Token has been revoked
>   at Request.extractError (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
>   at Request.callListeners (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
>   at Request.emit (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
>   at Request.emit (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
>   at Request.transition (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
>   at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
>   at /var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
>   at Request. (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
>   at Request. (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
>   at Request.callListeners (/var/task/sign-out/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
>   message: 'Access Token has been revoked',

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This exception throws as Access token you are using was already has been revoked by the global sign out it self.

Which means you have did already signed out from the cognito.

Try to invoke the same function with new Access Token generated by signing in (aka Login) API.